# How to generate the same random numbers in one language as in another?

Tags: java, python, r, random, stata

I am translating codes from Stata to R. The same random seed does not generate the same outputs. I am not sure if this is also the case in other languages (Python, Java etc.). How to generate identical random numbers in different languages?

Comment: The only real solution is to call the one language from the others

Comment: You will have to implement the same PRNG in all the languages you care about.  Can you show us in detail how you're encountering problems because the same random numbers are not being generated?

Comment: "Identical random numbers" is an oxymoron. If you want the same sequence of numbers, use the same generator with the same configs and inputs. If you want random numbers, then you're not supposed to complain when the numbers are different.

Comment: @Kayaman Isn't it common practice to say "random" when meaning pseudo-random? Even the tag does so.

Comment: @superbrain but it's not common to say "random" when you mean "deterministic", which is what the question is asking for.

Comment: To clarify. This is for class teaching purpose. I want students of either language to have identical results.

Comment: The only work-around I can think of to guarantee identical realizations across platforms is to generate a random number stream from 1 platform, export it and then read that into other platforms.

Comment: @Kayaman So if you replace the word "random" with "deterministic" in their question, you think that reads well and makes sense? I don't think so, as then the randomness aspect is completely missing. Saying "same random" is perfectly fine.

Comment: Suggest the comments on syntax that don't address the OP question be deleted as obtrusive.  Then I'll delete this suggestion too.

Comment: Implementing the [following algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030354/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-pseudo-random-number-without-using-a-languages-sta) in each language would probably be the path of least resistance.

Comment: Might be an interesting task (for your students!) to pick one algorithm from say https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators and implement it on different languages

Comment: Thank you all. I learned something today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R uses its own initialization method for the Mersenne-Twister (see `help("set.seed")`), which differs from what other languages do. The easiest way to ensure the same PRNG is used (and to avoid implementing something subpar yourself), is simply interfacing R and Stata and using the PRNG from either of these.

However, it's worth keeping in mind that achieving true reproducibility is impossible unless you are using exactly the same software on exactly the same hardware and OS. Thus, I wouldn't spent effort on trying to achieve the same PRNG streams with different software. Instead I would generate these numbers, store them and import them as needed.